# How do I load a library defined with hook_library() on node/edit pages?

Tags: 7, hooks, theming

I've defined a library of JavaScript files and CSS files required for my module to function using `hook_library()`.

How do I go about loading this library on node/edit pages?

Comment: Not sure why I've been voted down for asking this question. Clearly I looked at the docs first.

Comment: Update, just found this excellent page regarding JavaScript and Drupal 7: http://drupal.org/node/756722

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would call [`drupal_add_library()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7) in a [`hook_form_alter()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) implementation, like this:

```
function MODULE_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id) {
  if (isset($form['#node_edit_form']) && $form['#node_edit_form') {
    drupal_add_library('MODULE', 'LIBRARY');
  }
}
```

This should ensure the library is loaded whenever a node form is displayed.

And using hints from Berdir to use [`hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_BASE_FORM_ID_alter/7) and from kiamlaluno to use [`#attached`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#attached):

```
function MYMODULE_form_node_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state) {
  $form['#attached']['library'][] = array('MODULE', 'LIBRARY');
}
```

Comment: Doesn't answer how I then load that on node/edit pages? I'm looking for best practices here as there are always multiple ways of doing things?

Comment: You are right, I read the question quickly and misunderstood its intend.

Comment: Note: You can use MYMODULE_form_node_form_alter() in Drupal 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you are modifying, or outputting a form, you can use the [#attached](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/7#attached) attribute, which is described as "allows loading of CSS, Javascript, libraries, or custom types when the form is built".